# A ring in which Intersection and product of ideals are the same

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a ring such that for every ideals $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b} \subset R$ we have that $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$. Why is every prime ideal in $R$ maximal?

Comment: I don't think this is true if you don't assume that your ring is noetherian (e.g. $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$)

Comment: Why is the product of ideals and their intersection the same in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$?

Comment: Oh you didn't even say prime....you just said ALL ideals. Have you thought about what the implications are if you take $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{b}$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1\ne 0$ satisfying the specified hypothesis.

Initiating a proof by contradiction, suppose $P$ is a prime ideal which is not maximal.

Let $I$ be an ideal with proper inclusions $P\subset I\subset (1)$, and let $x\in I\setminus P$.

By hypothesis, $(x)(x)=(x)\cap (x)$, so $(x^2)=(x)$, hence $x=rx^2$ for some $r\in R$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
x=rx^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x(1-rx)=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x(1-rx)\in P
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
1-rx\in P&&\Big(\text{since $x\not\in P$}\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
1-rx\in I&&\Big(\text{since $P\subset I$}\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
1\in I&&\Big(\text{since $x\in I$}\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
I=(1)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.